# OpenNLP Name Finder training: Unsupported language: en

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, training-data, opennlp

I'm trying to test training OpenNLP's Name Finder on some data, according to the guide in the documentation. However, I encountered the error: `Unsupported language: en`, which doesn't seem to make any sense.

The command I ran is: `opennlp TokenNameFinderTrainer.conll03 -model model.bin -lang en -types per,loc,org,misc -data train.txt -encoding UTF-8`

I downloaded OpenNLP 1.9.0 from https://opennlp.apache.org/download.html. The `OPENNLP_HOME` environment variable does seem to be properly set, and the `lang` folder in the base folder contains an `en` folder.

---

EDIT: This seems to have something to do with the CoNLL2003 format. If I try to run the trainer directly without specifying `.conll2003` it works. However my input data is in CoNLL 2003 format. Running `TokenNameFinderConverter` gives me the same error. Even trying it on the official example https://github.com/apache/opennlp/blob/master/opennlp-tools/src/test/resources/opennlp/tools/formats/conll2003-en.sample doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

OK so apparently in a certain version after `1.5.3`, **for CoNLL-2003 related commands**, OpenNLP changed the language codes from two characters to three characters, i.e. one should have passed in `eng` instead of `en`. But the documentation was never updated on this. (There are various outdated portions of the documentation.) Was banging my head for 2 hours trying to figure it out! I made a PR to fix the documentation.